# How to split express router to separate files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking for a better way to manage my logic in express router.
This is a code snippet:

```
router.get('/get', function(req, res) {

  if(typeof req.query.category !== undefined){

    //do something

  }

});
```

...but puting my logic here will make the file grow very easily.

I though about this:

```
if(typeof req.query.category !== undefined){

   var gallery = new Gallery(req.query.category)

}
```

So I can handle stuff in seperate file

1)  if var Gallery exists in seperate file (ie. galleryManager.js) how can I include the file in my router?
2) What approach do you use?

Answer (score 4):

This is typically how I do it. I am by no means saying this is the best way to do it. But its an approach that works for me and keeps things a bit more organized.

**app.js** (*root*)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    .. view engine stuff ..
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

require('./controllers/index.js')(app);
require('./controllers/page2.js')(app);

//server
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ',  port);
```

**index.js** (*controller, or router*)

```
module.exports = function(app)
{   
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {      
        res.render('index', { });
    });
}
```

**File Structure**

```
   -controller
      -index.js
      -page2.js
   -static
     -css
     -js
     -img
   -views
     -index. (ejs, jade, mustache) // or whatever you prefer
   app.js
   package.json
```

**DEMO:**

https://github.com/krishollenbeck/express-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Your `galleryManager.js` file should look something like:

```
var Gallery = function Gallery(){
//...
}
//...
module.exports.Gallery = Gallery;
```

In your router/controller, to import do the following:

```
var Gallery = require('./galleryManager').Gallery
```

In the require above, you have to put in the path to your file.  This example assumes the files are all in the same directory